# Prevent NA from being used in a lm regresion

Tags: r, lm

I have a vector Y containing future returns and a vector X contain current returns. The last Y element is NA, as the last current return is also the very end of the available series.

```
X = { 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5 }
Y = { 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, NA }
Other = { 5500, 222, 523, 3677 }

lm(Y ~ X + Other)
```

I want to make sure that the last element of each series is **not** included in the regression. I read the na.action documentation but I'm not clear if this is the default behaviour.

For cor(), is this the correct solution to exclude X[4] and Y[4] from the calculation?

```
cor(X, Y, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The factory-fresh default for `lm` is to disregard observations containing `NA` values. Since this could be overridden using global options, you might want to explicitly set `na.action` to `na.omit`:

```
> summary(lm(Y ~ X + Other, na.action=na.omit))

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X + Other, na.action = na.omit)

[snip]

  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As to your second question `cor(X,Y,use='pairwise.complete.obs')` is correct. Since there are only two variables, `cor(X,Y,use='complete.obs')` would also produce the expected result.

Comment: You might want to clarify the reason behind your final sentence: with only two vectors being correlated, `pairwise.complete.obs` and `complete.obs` are equivalent.  With more vectors (i.e. taking the correlations of all the columns in a matrix), they wouldn't be ...