# Plot linear regression on time vs cq with cq values missing for some time intervals

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I want to apply linear regression for time vs cq in R. The problem is that for some intervals of time I have obtained no cq values. The data is given below:

`time   cq
0hr    17.1
       15.54
       13.49
       15.71
       12.98
        9
16hr    8.33
       No Cq
       No Cq
       7.54
       No Cq
       20.86
24hr    8.85
       28.51
       No Cq
       19.07
       9.27
       11.31
30hr   14.23
       10.51
       13.9
       16.9
       10.72
       8.74
42hr   No Cq
       No Cq
       No Cq
       No Cq
       No Cq
       No Cq
 48hr  25.61
       25.13
       21.28
       22.49
       21.92
       22.95`

I know how to apply linear model on a plot in R but I want to ask what should be done for No Cq, should I put NA at their place ?

Comment: You can do linear interpolation if you want, can you do `dput(yourdata)` and I can show you how to do it.

Comment: What if  make two vectors one for cq and second for time interval , so the vectors would be like this ` y = (17.1,15.54,13.49,15.71,12.98,9,NA) ,x = (0,0,0,0,0,0)...`

Comment: and plot these two vectors and put NA for missing values and then apply a linear model to my plot ? Will it lead to wrong plot ?

Comment: It should not be a problem, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448019/r-lm-na-action). If that does not answer your question let me know